# Zero cost abstraction for executing same statement on multiple objects

Tags: c++, abstraction, code-duplication

Assume three objects `A a`, `B b` and `C c`. All three have a method with the signature `void foo(Bar& bar)`.

Sometimes I need to write the following code:

```cs
a.foo(bar);
b.foo(bar);
c.foo(bar);
```

Now that is a lot of code duplication, especially once the expression gets longer.

So far, I have come up with

```cpp
foreach (const auto& value : { a, b, c}) value.foo(bar);
```

But that only works if `a`, `b` and `c` are of the same type, and `foo` is `const`.

*Is there an elegant zero-cost abstraction to abstract the free identical method calls at once, for different types and non-const functions?*

This would preferably work on arbitrary statements involving `value`.

Comment: Do `A`, `B`, and `C` have a common base class? If not, why not?

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica as I understand, using inheritance requires pointers to the objects, and a virtual method table lookup. Which would make this less efficient than writing out the 3 lines directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap them into a function template, with the help of [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

```
template <typename... T>
void call_bar(Bar& bar, const T&... t) {
    (t.foo(bar), ...);
}
```

then

```
call_bar(bar, a, b, c);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/f4aEwOmtl0SjXaQv)

Comment: Is there a way to abstract this for any set of values? e.g. by passing a templated function which works for each `T...`

Comment: @Dracam You might pass a specialization of the function template, or you can wrap into a functor class and pass it, depending on the context.

Comment: I can't find a way to code this for multiple different `T`s. I don't even think that the type system allows this. So I was experimenting with macros, but couldn't get stuff to work.

Comment: @Dracam do you mean `template <typename F, typename... T> void apply(F&& f, T&&... t) { (f(t), ...); }` used like `apply([&](auto & t){ t.foo(bar); }, a, b, c)`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself for up to 5 arguments with clever macros:

```
// Does not work on MSVC, since they use a different preprocessor algorithm than clang and gcc.
// Use like this:
//   foreach(const &, myFoo1, myFoo2, myFoo3, _.foo());
//   foreach(&&, a, b, c, sum += _);

#define _GET_FOR_EACH_MACRO(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, NAME, ...) \
    NAME

#define _FOR_EACH1(refMod, _1, expr) \
    { auto refMod _ = _1; (expr); };

#define _FOR_EACH2(refMod, _1, _2, expr) \
    { auto refMod _ = _1; (expr); }; \
    _FOR_EACH1(refMod, _2, expr)

#define _FOR_EACH3(refMod, _1, _2, _3, expr) \
    { auto refMod _ = _1; (expr); }; \
    _FOR_EACH2(refMod, _2, _3, expr)

#define _FOR_EACH4(refMod, _1, _2, _3, _4, expr) \
    { auto refMod _ = _1; (expr); }; \
    _FOR_EACH3(refMod, _2, _3, _4, expr)

#define _FOR_EACH5(refMod, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, expr) \
    { auto refMod _ = _1; (expr); }; \
    _FOR_EACH4(refMod, _2, _3, _4, _5, expr)

#define foreach(...) _GET_FOR_EACH_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, _FOR_EACH5, _FOR_EACH4, _FOR_EACH3, _FOR_EACH2, _FOR_EACH1)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

For some reason this doesn't work with MSVC 2019, as `__VAR_ARG__` is passed as a single argument to other macros, not as multiple arguments. It does work fine on Clang and GCC though.